# Laravel get paramater from url in blade

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-8

I want to write in blade second parameter of URL

```
{{ Request::get('urlNumber') }}
```

I using this but it is not showing parameter in blade.

IN Route: `Route::get('/{id}/policydetail/{urlNumber}','MerchantDashboardController@policydetail');`

Exam Url:: http://127.0.0.1:8001/backoffice/5896/policydetail/2

Comment: Why not just pass it to your view from your Controller?

Answer (score 3):

@brombeer's suggestion of passing the `urlNumber` param from the Controller to the view is the correct approach, but you can access URL Params via the `->parameter()` method:

https://laravel.com/api/8.x/Illuminate/Routing/Route.html#method_parameter.

In your case:

```
{{ request()->route()->parameter('urlNumber') }}
```

The `request()->get()` method you're trying to use is for getting a value from a Query String, like `?urlNumber=123`. Url Parameters `{urlNumber}` are not the same as Query String parameters, so that code will not work here.